# @InjectMocks is not injecting dependencies properly

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

I have a code where @InjectMocks is not able to add second level mocked dependencies.

```
public class Token{
    //setters getters and logic
}

public class TokenManager{
    public Token getToken(){
        //Some logic to return token
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private TokenManager tmgr;
    public MyClass(TokenManager tmgr){
        this.tmgr = tmgr;
    }
    public void doLogic(){
        Token token = tmgr.getToken();
        String tokenStr = token.getString();
        //Logic
    }
}

@Run(MockitoJunit4)
public class MyClassTest{
    @Mock 
    TokenManager tmgr;
    
    @Mock
    Token token;
    
    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;
    
    @Begin
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void doLogicTest{
        String sometestStr = "ABCD";
        when(tmg.getToken()).thenReturn(token);
        when(token.getString()).thenReturn(sometestSTR);
        
        myClass.doLogic();
        
        //some asserts
        
    }
}
```

Code is returning NullPointer at
`String tokenStr = token.getString()`
I am not able to do Junit testing for because of this. If i add these mocked dependencies via constructor of MyClass, it works

Comment: Do you understand what a _mock object_ is? Note that in most cases (including here) you should not mock _data_ such as `Token`.

Comment: Sorry, I have given a wrong example. All I needed to mock objects created inside methods. Dimitrii's below solution is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has some problems with annotations and mocking objects. Try to change code in the test class like that:

```
public class MyClassTest {

@Mock 
TokenManager tmgr;

@InjectMocks
MyClass myClass;

@Before
public void setup(){
  initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void doLogicTest {
    Token token = mock(Token.class);
    String sometestStr = "ABCD";
    when(tmg.getToken()).thenReturn(token);
    when(token.getString()).thenReturn(sometestSTR);
    
    myClass.doLogic();
    
    //some asserts
    
}
```

}